# Remove all symbols except ones contained within two letters, using RegEx

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Using Python and regex, I need to remove a certain character (e.g., `-`) from a string, except if it is a single character placed between two alpha characters.

For example:

```
'--abc-def - --g--h 1-2'  ==> 'abc-def  gh 12'
```

Comment: What'd be the expected output for `abc---def`... are those `-`'s between two characters or is it only *single* characters between two characters... ?

Comment: Keep only single characters between two letters. in that case you would remove all three '-'.

Comment: okay... can you [edit] that into your question... people would probably like to see what you've tried with `regex` so far as well - could well be you're close and it just needs a tweak for instance?

Comment: Something like `(?<![a-zA-Z])-|-(?![a-zA-Z])`?

Comment: @Sweeper That's a nice one.

Comment: @Sweeper that seems to do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])-|-(?![a-zA-Z])
```

like this:

```
result = re.sub(r"(?<![a-zA-Z])-|-(?![a-zA-Z])", "", your_string)
# or with re.I
result = re.sub(r"(?<![a-z])-|-(?![a-z])", "", your_string, re.I)
```

Explanation:

The regex can match one of these two things:

- `-` that doesn't have a letter before it: `(?<![a-zA-Z])-`
- `-` that doesn't have a `letter` after it: `-(?![a-zA-Z])`

A `-` that is surrounded by letters does not satisfy any of the requirements above, so it will not be matched.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/momMgP/1)